# CMake doesn't link C and C++ static libraries (undefined reference to function)

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I tried to reproduce minimal problem. When I run CMake+Make on Ubuntu I get error

`` funccpp.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `FuncC' ``

i.e. exported function in C library is not found when importing in C++ library. When I try to manually compile using `g++ main.cpp funcc.c funccpp.cpp` it successfully compiles final program. How to fix CMake issue?

For reference, when I run `nm libfuncc_lib.a` I get line `T FuncC` (so symbol is external and defined in Text section), when I run `nm libfunccpp_lib.a` I get `U FuncC` (so symbol is Undefined and should be linked from outside).

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(Test C CXX)

set (SRC_CPP funccpp.cpp)
set (SRC_C funcc.c)
set (SRC_MAIN main.cpp)

add_library(funcc_lib STATIC ${SRC_C})
add_library(funccpp_lib STATIC ${SRC_CPP})
add_executable(prog ${SRC_MAIN})
target_link_libraries(prog funcc_lib funccpp_lib)
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "funccpp.h"

int main() {
    FuncCPP();
    return 0;
}
```

**funccpp.h**

```
#ifndef FUNCCPP_H
#define FUNCCPP_H

void FuncCPP();

#endif
```

**funccpp.cpp**

```
#include "funcc.h"

void FuncCPP() {
    FuncC();
}
```

**funcc.h**

```
#ifndef FUNCC_H
#define FUNCC_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void FuncC();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // FUNCC_H
```

**funcc.c**

```
#include "funcc.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void FuncC() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
}
```

Comment: Try using 'target_link_libraries(prog funccpp_lib funcc_lib)' instead of 'target_link_libraries(prog funcc_lib funccpp_lib)' since your C++ lib depdends on C lib.

Comment: What happens if you switch the order of libraries to `target_link_libraries(prog funccpp_lib funcc_lib)`?

Comment: Not sure about CMake and 'target_link_libraries', but for single-pass LD linker implementation it instructs the linker to search symbols for 'funccpp_lib' in 'funcc_lib', not vice versa.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here is, that the linker relies on the order of the libraries. With

```
target_link_libraries(prog funcc_lib funccpp_lib)
```

It first links `funcc_lib` and then `funccpp_lib`. But it never gets back to `funcc_lib`. Since `funccpp_lib` depends on `funcc_lib`, you have to change the order of the libraries:

```
target_link_libraries(prog funccpp_lib funcc_lib)
```

[For additional information, see this discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409470/579698)

Comment: Thanks! Issue fixed. But what to do with cases when there are two libraries A and B, where there is cyclic dependency - A needs some functions from B and vice versa?

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul Have a look at the link, I provided: Simply list the libs multiple times, i.e. `target_link_libraries(prog funccpp_lib funcc_lib funccpp_lib)`

Comment: Even better, tell CMake that `funccpp_lib` depends on `funcc_lib`: `target_link_libraries(funccpp_lib funcc_lib)`.

Answer (score 0):

Make cmake c link command as c++ commmand will solve the problem

```
SET(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE ${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE})
```